# Uploading to locker in Desire2Learn

Tags: desire2learn

I'm encountering a problem uploading a file to a locker in D2L's API. Send data is below.

I'm getting a 404 error in response to this. I've tried using 'test2.jpg' and content-type of image/jpeg, I've also tried plaintext instaed of binary and using text/plain as a content-type.

Any advice would be helpful

Thanks.

```
POST /d2l/api/le/1.0/locker/myLocker/test?<auth Keys> HTTP/1.1  
User-Agent: PECL::HTTP/1.6.1-dev (PHP/5.2.6)  
Host: <server>
Accept: */*  
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=BOUND  
Content-Length: 252  

--BOUND  
Content-Type: application/json  

{"Description":"test2.tst", "IsPublic":false}  
--BOUND  
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename="test2.tst"  
Content-Type: application/x-octetstream  

<base64_encoded string>
--BOUND--
```

Comment: Two possible points with your example: (a) the filename you provide for the uploaded file data might have to have a file extension that's in accordance with the stated Content-Type (but perhaps not); (b) the POST request probably needs a top-level Content-Length header that describes the total size of the POST body data (all parts).

Comment: I've updated with a paste of the actual HTTP request. This is still returning an error - I get a 302 error redirecting to a 404 page.

Comment: It's possible that the request is not finding the folder location to place the file at: (a) make sure the 'test' folder does exist as a child folder of your locker root folder, and (b) make sure your route ends with a trailing slash (/d2l/api/le/1.0/locker/myLocker/test/), perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback; The test folder does indeed exist, I created it using the same request and have verified that it exists in the locker. I've tried both with and without a trailing slash, as well as setting the path to an empty string in an attempt to put the file at the lockers' root.

I've also tried using .jpg extensions and type image/jpeg, as well as type application/binary.

Comment: What LMS product version is your back-end instance? 9.4.1?

Comment: We have produced a successful test to upload to a calling user's locker on a v10 test instance using this API route. The only difference in the HTTP sent that I can see is the route on our end has a trailing slash. Otherwise, the two HTTP blocks are functionally the same (same headers, and etc, etc). This leads me to believe that you have a permissions issue of some sort, or perhaps your locker doesn't have sufficient space left to handle the uploaded data?

Comment: I've added the trailing slash, and confirmed that the folder does indeed exist. Currently the locker is using 35 bytes of 1,000 KB, so there is plenty of room for the file. Do you know where I can verify the permissions?

Comment: Not sure exactly what permissions are involved in Locker uploads. The next step might be to escalate to the next stage of support (http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/about.html#support) and file an issue with D2L's issue tracker...

Comment: Thanks for all the help Viktor! Turns out the issue was that I was issuing only newline's (\n) instead of carriage return/newline (\r\n) in my headers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to ensure that the header is using \r\n instead of just \n to separate sections.